# Create identifier without using by or sort commands

Tags: stata

I have a panel dataset that does not have either id or year variable. But I know  that the data is ordered so that every seven observations represent an individual and each of the seven observations represents a year. I need to create the individual id variable but I don't know how to do that without using the Stata commands `by:` and `sort`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess that whoever did was reacting to absence of code, construed as lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to proceed. One is to use the `egen` function `seq()` to create sequence variables.

```
egen long id = seq(), block(7)
```

The explicit `long` will be needed with large datasets. With this syntax identifiers will run 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 and so forth.

```
egen year = seq(), from(1) to(7)
```

Clearly you should replace `1` and `7` by actual start and end years if you know them.

The `egen` function here is just a wrapper for more basic functions and commands. Here is another way to do it:

```
gen id2 = ceil(_n/7)
gen year2 = mod(_n - 1, 7) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly. And I'm sorry I didn't provide any initial code, I honestly had no idea what to do.